# SPRING - @Autowired and @Service does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I know that exists a lot of questions of that, i read a lot and no one can help me. Thanks for helping me.

I dont like the spring way to define every bean in xml so i used a scanner in my apllication context but i think that only sacan the @Component (my managed beans) but it dont wanna catch the @Service and @Repository, i said that cuz my Service is null.

Thats the spring stuff in web.xml

```
<!-- Archivo de configuraciones de Spring y JSF -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:WEB-INF/context/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Línea especial para la integración con un Java-based web framework (JSF) -->    
    <listener>
        <listener-lass>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Thats my application-context.xml

```
 <context:spring-configured/>     

    <!-- Escanear todos los componentes y beans en vez de instanciar 1 por 1 -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="paquete" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <!-- Identificar todos los beans por las anotaciones -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Archivo de propiedades configurables (database, messages, etc) -->
    <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath*:META-INF/*.properties"/>


    <!-- Gestor de transacciones de SPRING -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"     id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- El conversador entre nuestras entidades y las tablas de BD -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Integración de Spring e Hibernate, no es obligatorio -->
    <bean id="vendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Formalidad de dataSource de SPRING -->
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>
```

In my package "paquete" (package in spanish, im from Peru sorry for my bad english) i have 3 subpackages, so in netbeans i see 3 packages like "paquete.beans", "paquete.service" and "paquete.repositorios". im called with the component scanner in the "paquete" package

Im using primefaces so y hace a helloJSFBean that is..

```
 @ManagedBean
    @Scope("session")
    @Component
    public class helloPageJSFBean {

        private String nombre;
        private String nombre2;

        public String getNombre2() {
            return nombre2;
        }

        public void setNombre2(String nombre2) {
            this.nombre2 = nombre2;
        }

        @Autowired
        HelloService helloService;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            nombre="hi";
        }

        public void saludar(ActionEvent actionEvent){
            nombre2=helloService.saludar(nombre);
        }


        /* 
         *Getters and Setters
         */
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

    }
```

so i call my helloService and is...

```
  @Service
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService{

    @Autowired
    protected HelloRepository helloRepository;

    @Override
    public String saludar(String nombre) {
        return helloRepository.saludar(nombre);
    }

}
```

and my repository is

```
  @Repository
    public class HelloRepositoryImpl implements HelloRepository {

        @Override
        public String saludar(String nombre) {
            return "Hola "+nombre+", estás haciendo un excelente trabajo";
        }

    }
```

---

The problem is that i get the `NullPointerException` in my "saludar" method, in the debug my service is null and is not a instance of helloServiceImpl, so i guess the @Autowired its not workin.

All help that i recive it will be great, i have losted 2 weeks and nothing. Thank all.

Comment: Is the service located under the paquete package? like...paquete.some.package.path.HelloServiceImpl ?

Comment: In which "saludar" you get the exception?

Comment: Yes, "paquete" package is the main package and i have 3 packages inside, so i have the packages: "paquete.beans", "paquete.repository" and "paquete.service". My partner work says thats its ok that should read the services and repositories.

I get the nullPointer in the "saludar" method in the helloJSFBean when im callin the service.saludar(name). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i dont knew why use classpath in the definition of the location of the files, so, i think about classpath and when someone put "classpath*:directory/file.ext" forces the IDE to search that files in the SRC path when the java classes are put on it. And obviuslly theres no folders in there (in my configuration proyect) so y remove the classpath on the definition and it works.

So if this is usefull to anybody im happy from that. And i want to thank all of u for the time and the consideration to answer. thanks !!

Thats my project structure,. Im working on netbeans, this page says i cant post images, well let you the link

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/6338/sinttulofwk.png

And my configuration files...

Web.xml

```
 <!-- Archivo de configuraciones de Spring y JSF -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/context/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
...
...  
<!-- Archivo de propiedades configurables (database, messages, etc) -->
<context:property-placeholder  location="META-INF/database.properties"/>
...
...
 <!-- El conversador entre nuestras entidades y las tablas de BD -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="WEB-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdapter" />
</bean>
```

If someone can tell my if the classpath idea its rigth or wrong ill be thankfull. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/jsf-2-primefaces-3-spring-3-hibernate-4.html) page, you need to set:

```
   <!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->
   <application>
     <el-resolver>
      org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
     </el-resolver>
   </application>
```

in your **faces-config.xml**, and reference the Spring bean using `@ManagedProperty(value="#{name of your service}")` instead of `@Autowired`.

Comment: I'll  try that, in the example proyect that im use to guide me they dont use the ManagedProperty, only Service and Repository annotation and in the component scanner call the main package. Thank u i will try and comment

Comment: Im sorry, thats nor working. I did what u said and i still haeving the nullpointer. I put a postconstruct in a bean, service and repository with a println saying hi, and only the bean says hi, the service and the repository arent initializing, thanks 4 help

Comment: But the other beans (entityManagerFactory, transactionManager) are being initialized, right?

Comment: I dont see nothig about entityManagerFactory, transactionManager in the log.. in this moment i dont have any entity in my proyect, im starting with the services and that stuff and when i get that ok ill starting with the entities. I make the reference to bd a one single table with 2 attributes. How i can get assurance of initialization of those beans ?

Comment: If your service is instantiated by Spring, then add a transactionManager or entityManagerFactory to your service (with setter or autowiring), and check that they are not null. You can remove them later.

Comment: My service is not instantaited, is null in my bean, I get transactionManager and entityManagerFactory in my applicationContext